# Ubuntu само по себе изменилось окно входа в систему с очень подозрительным поведением

Tags: linux, ubuntu, безопасность, вирусы

После перезагрузки окно входа в систему нормальное, самое обычное как на всех убунту. Но стоит мне перейти в **режим сна** и выйти из него, вместо того что бы показать стандартное окно выбора пользователя и ввода пароля на убунту, мне **показывается непонятное окно без стилизации, имя пользователя, строка ввода пароля и всего две кнопки (switch user и unlock)**.

Мне кажется это окно странным по следующим причинам:
1) Когда нажимаю на "сменить пользователя" экран мигает и появляется стандартное окно ввода пароля для убунту. Но стоит ввести пароль экран сразу меняется на этот, без стилей, и требует вновь ввести пароль.
2) Это окно появляется ТОЛЬКО когда я выхожу из режима сна. То есть, КАК МНЕ КАЖЕТСЯ, как будто если включить ВЫКЛЮЧЕННЫЙ ноут и после загрузки убунту полностью, и сразу после того как я ввожу в нормальное окно убунту пароль - инициализируется какой то зловред и программа прописывает своё окно что бы после режиме сна пользователь ввёл свой пароль.

В общем товарищи у меня паранойя ещё по одной причине... Странности на компе начались сразу после того как я установил Винду как дополнительную ось... Обновления со всеми "Игрушками Штирлица" к сожалению были загружены (я тогда не знал про них). И что ещё удивительней, не знаю с каких это пор но винда начала определять ОС-и на компе и предлагать выбор загрузки ОС-и. Меня терзают смутные сомнения по поводу рут доступа. За любую подсказку **Заранее благодарю.** К сожалению сделать скрин экрана не представляется возможным так как всё заблокировано(как при стандартной операции "сменить юзера")

Comment: судя по описанию, вы наблюдаете экран блокировки. можете проверить, выбрав пункт «lock screen» в том же меню, где всякие «logout» и «switch user» находятся.

Comment: Да вы правы (параноик мод off) Как оказалось это древний баг аж с 2011 года. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-design/+bug/878836 вот подробней тут.

Comment: "И что ещё удивительней, не знаю с каких это пор но винда начала определять ОС-и на компе и предлагать выбор загрузки ОС-и. " Прааавда? Я думал, венда не умеет линухи бутить.

Comment: Вот похожий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/495814/185618). Разница в том, что  Dual Boot и Windows стояли с самого начала,а «особенный» экран показывают только одному пользователю из нескольких.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось это древний баг. Наблюдается с версии 11. Подробно https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-design/+bug/878836
Мне помогла переустановка Gnom-овского локера:
Удалим

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-screensaver
```

Перезагрузим потом установим

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-screensaver
```

Comment: Мне не помогло :(

Comment: более полутора лет назад я задала на [ru.so] [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/495814/Переключение-виртуальной-консоли-дает-зайти-без-пароля), а потом [такой же](https://askubuntu.com/questions/737801/switching-terminals-with-ctrl-altfn-does-not-require-password) на [ubuntu.se]. Сейчас дырку в безопасности закрыли и я на свой вопрос я ответила со ссылкой на ваш вопрос (раньше я его не видела). Может, вы хотите ответить на мой [вопрос](https://askubuntu.com/questions/737801/switching-terminals-with-ctrl-altfn-does-not-require-password) на [ubuntu.se]?