# Переключение виртуальной консоли дает зайти без пароля

Tags: ubuntu, безопасность

На компьютере с Ubuntu 14.04 есть несколько пользователей.
У всех пользователей включены опции спрашивать пароль при выходе из спящего режима и при разблокировке экрана. Экран выключается при бездействии в несколько минут и затем блокируется.
Но оказалось, что можно зайти к пользователю и без ввода пароля!  Я нашла  несколько сценариев, как это может произойти (но происходит не всегда):

- В систему входят не менее двух пользователей.
- Пользователь А нажимает `Блокировка/смена пользователя`,
  либо отходит от компьютера на время, достаточное для блокировки экрана.
- Появляется приветствие, которое спрашивает пароль, или черный экран.
  (Черный экран — это известная проблема, связанная то ли с драйвером, то ли с lightdm, примеры описания: [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/608737/switch-user-leads-to-black-screen) и  [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483281/unable-to-switch-users-without-logging-out-in-ubuntu-14-04). Для того, чтобы выйти из черного экрана, мы пользуемся `Ctrl`+ `Alt`+`Fn`.)
  Теперь можно предположить, что его консоль пользователя А заблокирована.
- Нажимаем `Ctrl`+ `Alt`+`Fn`, где `Fn` соответствует пользователю А.
- Открывается консоль пользователя А. Иногда это его приветствие , где нужно ввести пароль, но довольно часто — просто его консоль без пароля.

Иногда пользователь А у себя в консоли может нажать `Ctrl`+ `Alt`+`Fn`, где `Fn` соответствует пользователю Б, и открывается консоль пользователя Б.

Среди нескольких пользователей есть один, к которому гораздо чаще можно попасть таким способом. Я пробовала выставить ему разные настройки, определяющие когда вводить пароль, но они на эту проблему не влияют.
У этого же пользователя приветствие  не такое, как у остальных. У всех приветствие в левой части экрана показывает имя пользователя и поле для ввода пароля, как [здесь](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unIl6.png), а у этого — все данные посередине экрана, в другой верстке и с кнопкой «Переключить пользователя». То есть это другое приветствие, и я не понимаю, почему и где это определяется. (Я не уверена, что это связано с проблемой входа без пароля.)

Дисплейный менеджер:

```
cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
/usr/sbin/lightdm
```

Конфигурация lightdm:

```
sudo cat /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=unity-greeter
user-session=ubuntu
autologin-user=
allow-guest=false
```

Видеокарта:

```
sudo lshw -C video  
*-display              
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: 4th Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 06
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:44 memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

Мой вопрос:
Как сделать, чтобы при переключении пользователя требовался ввод пароля?

Comment: сформулируйте, пожалуйста, сам **вопрос**. внести изменения можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: по-моему, вопрос слишком абстрактен и всеобъемлющ. для его конкретизации вам надо выявить программу(-ы), осуществляющие блокировку x-сессии (я надеюсь, речь в вашем вопросе всё-таки о них, хотя и нет чёткого указания на это) и разбираться с их (не)работоспособностью. если вы не знаете, как выявить — задавайте новый вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается, похожий вопрос был [уже задан](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/458098/185618) ранее, но там речь идет лишь про приветствие. 
Старинный баг [878836](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-design/+bug/878836) виноват как в проблеме со входом без пароля, так и в необычном приветствии.
В настоящее время баг частично починили, и зайти без пароля уже невозможно. Правда, теперь пароль спрашивают два раза, но это лучше, чем совсем не спрашивать.
Согласно последнему комментарию бага на launchpad (от 2016-04-04), он починится до конца после перехода на Unity8 + Mir.

Comment: Но ведь уже не будет ни Unity8, ни Mir? :(

Comment: После перехода на GNOME.

Comment: @andreymal, см. обновление ответа. Я просто процитировала, что пишет launchpad.